# Text doesn't show up as it has to! (string)

Tags: java, android, boolean, preferences, shared

Ok, thanks to below dude biggest issue is fixed. But whatever I print out, none is printed and I cannot print out the message what is typed in class 2 (nimekysija) as well :(. I really need that it stores name and in future it will write down name every time! Thanks for your help!

Problem must be in 2nd class tho. When I update                     editor.putString("nimi2", nimiS); nimiS into "plapla", then plapla actually shows up :/. So I have really no idea, what is problem!

(updated below classes too to the newest)

---

Class 1:

```
package viimane.voimalus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainStuff extends Activity {
    TextView tere;
    String nimi;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        tere = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTere);
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        boolean nimiOlemas = preferences.getBoolean("nimionolemas", false);
        if (nimiOlemas == false){
             startActivity(new Intent("viimane.voimalus.NIMEKYSIJA"));
             finish();
        }
        if (nimiOlemas == true){
            nimi = preferences.getString("nimi2", "");
            System.out.print("töötab!");

            tere.setText("Tere " + nimi);
        }
        System.out.print("töötab2!");
    }
}
```

---

CLASS 2

```
package viimane.voimalus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class nimekysija extends Activity {

    EditText nimi;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    String nimiS;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nimekysija);
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        nimi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNimekysija);
        nimiS = nimi.getText().toString();
        Button kysOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNimekysija);
        kysOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {      

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("nimi2", nimiS); // nime kirjutamine
                editor.putBoolean("nimionolemas", true); // nimi on kirjutatud!
                editor.commit();
                startActivity(new Intent("viimane.voimalus.MAINSTUFF"));
                finish();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. I am not able to understand your question, 2. Provide a stacktrace of the specific error you are getting.

Comment: 1. Basically: It doesn't still work for some reason. Did i put some codes wrong? It doesnt work as I explained up there as it should work! 2. The Local variable nimiOlemas is never read (I noted it just so maybe it gives hint what might be wrong)

Comment: I found one bug: "viimane.voimalus.MAIN" was wrong, (actually I am not sure). But still, might be the true and false be wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'm guessing you may be new to Java, forgive me if I'm incorrect.  You never READ from nimiOlemas.

```
 boolean nimiOlemas = preferences.getBoolean("nimionolemas", false);
    nimiOlemas = false;
                startActivity(new Intent("viimane.voimalus.NIMEKYSIJA"));
                finish();
               nimiOlemas = true;
```

I think what you are trying to do is initialize nimiOlemas and then, if it is false, start an activity, call finish, then set nimiOlemas to true, but this is not what you are doing.  Is this what you want?

```
boolean nimiOlemas = preferences.getBoolean("nimionolemas", false);
if (nimiOlemas == false)
{
     startActivity(new Intent("viimane.voimalus.NIMEKYSIJA"));
     finish();
     nimiOlemas = true;
}
```

= is an assignment, == is a boolean comparison.  You say in your question that you check the value of your boolean, but you never do, you only assign to it.

Comment: I checked out and it seems that == was my biggest mistake :). Thank you. Yes, I am new to Java :). But there seems still small problem. Later it doesn't write out whatever I type into the EditText

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that nimiOlemas is inherited from activity and not used in the activity class, or other supper class, then yes it is not used in nimekysija (Class 2).  It IS used in class 1.  But this should just be a warning...  You will get this warning for every class that extends activity and doesn't use nimiOlemas.

Comment: But didn't I use it? nimiOlemas = false;
 Or I used it wrong way?

Comment: Thats in Class 1, you said you were getting this error in class 2.  Regardless, unless you READ from a variable, you'll get a warning because the IDE wants to know why you created it to hold data you never used.

Comment: I see, lemme check the upper thing you said! Thank you very much!